# How to send images from Unity to Django through Json type

Tags: json, django, unity-game-engine, request

I want an image request between Django and Unity. So, I want to send the image data to Json type using UnityWebRequest.

The source code below is Unity C # code.

```
public void onClickSendButton(){
    coroutine = ServerThrows();
    StartCoroutine(coroutine);
}

IEnumerator ServerThrows()
{
    string imageAsJson = File.ReadAllText(imagePath);
    byte[] bodyRaw = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(imageAsJson);
    UnityWebRequest www = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST");
    www.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler) new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
    www.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler) new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
    www.chunkedTransfer = false;
    www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");

    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if(www.isNetworkError||www.isHttpError){
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        GetResponse(www);
    }
}
```

Here is the Django Server Code:

```
def fromunity(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    print(data)
    print(request.content_type)
    return HttpResponse()
```

In Unity, when I send a request through onClickSendButton, Django Server shows the following results:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfQNl.png)

(json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0))

Depending on the Django Server results above, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a question of what form Json was made. 
Json can simply represent Unity's wwwform as a string. So, I could construct the form as follows.

```
string form = "{\'image\':\'String representation of the image\'}"
```

It was my ignorance of Json.